# Gigabyte B460m ds3h incompatibility with 3060ti on Ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, hardware, bug-reporting

I recently brought a Gigabyte B460M DS3H AC motherboard and a Zotec 3060 ti. I run a fresh install of Kubuntu and everything was working fine until i connected the Graphics Card. During the boot up it just gets stuck on the Gigabyte screen. I took it to a computer tech and they managed to get it running on Windows, but this is far from ideal.

Some other specs:

- version groovy gorilla 20.1
- Intel i3 10100 cpu
- latest bios version (F5a)

I tried install Ubuntu via Grub and got these errors -

1. Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
2. nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (b74000a1)
3. usb 1-7: unable to read config index0 descriptor/start: -32
4. usb 1-7: chopping to 0 config(s)
5. usb 1-7: cant read configurations, error -32
6. usb 1-7: cant set config #1 error -71
7. usb usb1-port7: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling ...

Any ideas, thanks

Comment: Some specific information about the system is needed in order to provide any realistic suggestions. Which specific version of Kubuntu did you install? Does the machine boot properly with a Live USB? Are there any error logs or specific details that can be shared? As it is, there's no realistic way for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: @Matigo version groovy gorilla 20.1, no error logs just freezing during boot, Intel i3 10100 cpu, latest bios version (F5a)

Comment: @Matigo i tried install Ubuntu via Grub and got the errors above

Comment: If you are trying to install, it appears that your system does boot properly from a Live USB. If this is true, Please do so and issue the command `lsusb -vvv |grep -i -B5 -A5 bcdUSB` and include the output in your question. Thank you for helping us help you!